# How write C macro?

Tags: c

Now I have the follow macro:

```
#define PHP_FREE_WRAPPED_FUNC_START(name, class_type) \
    void free_##class_type(void *name) { \
        class_type *p = (class_type *)name;
#define PHP_FREE_WRAPPED_FUNC_END() \
        zend_object_std_dtor(&p->std TSRMLS_CC); \
        efree(p); \
    }
```

Then I want to get `free_test1(void *object)` function, so I will use:

```
PHP_FREE_WRAPPED_FUNC_START(object, test1)
    printf("test1\n");
PHP_FREE_WRAPPED_FUNC_END()
```

And I want to get `free_test2(void *object)` function, so I will use:

```
PHP_FREE_WRAPPED_FUNC_START(object, test2)
    printf("test2\n");
PHP_FREE_WRAPPED_FUNC_END()
```

But `##` can not join `free` and `test1` to get `free_test1`, why?

Comment: This is not C but C++ preprocessor, but [couldn't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/GMEX9JV1CZEMVw32). Isn't what you actually want to ask how to prevent `}` from being commented out?

Comment: Remember that the back-slash at the end of the line is a line **continuation** character, meaning that the current line and the next line will be concatenated into a single line. If you have line-comments those will expand to the end of the concatenated line. You should tell your compiler to stop after the preprocessing step so you can see the preprocessed code and make sure it matches what you expects.

Comment: `// common end code \ `  --> `/* common end code */\ `

Comment: why do you change the code so that it makes a vast difference?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Because I say not clear before and change code to re-description this. thanks.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks a lot.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just simplify your code and ran that, the code you post can work, `##` can join the `free_` and `class_type` together.

```
#define PHP_FREE_WRAPPED_FUNC_START(name, class_type)\
    void free_##class_type(void *name) {\
        printf("%s\n",name);
#define PHP_FREE_WRAPPED_FUNC_END()\
        printf("End\n");\
}\

PHP_FREE_WRAPPED_FUNC_START(hello,test1)
    printf("Middle\n");
PHP_FREE_WRAPPED_FUNC_END()

int main(void)
{
    free_test1("start");
    return 0;
}
```

And It worked well.

I saw the comments are about the `backslash`. I guess you have fixed the error.

Comment: I can also run it on PHP5, but can not run it on PHP7. errors: `error: implicit declaration of function 'test1_from_obj' is invalid in C99`

Comment: The error means that you need to declare the function first.  I suggest you to create a new macro, like: `#define PHP_FREE_WRAPPED_FUNC_DECLARE(name, class_type) \
      void free_##class_type(void *name)`

Comment: @thinkerou  And declare it  `PHP_FREE_WRAPPED_FUNC_START(object, test2);` That may work

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the C++ style comments you are using (//) comment out the line continuation (\) needed for the macro.  You can solve this by either moving the comments outside of the macro definition, or by using C style comments (/* */), like that:

```
#define FUNC_END() \
    /* common end code */
}
```

But for such small macros, you probably don't even need to use two lines:

```
// common end code
#define FUNC_END() }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot your suggestion.